# php ">" without question mark acts like "?>"

Tags: php, html

I have a page, where there is a script in the footer.

```
<?php
    require_once('../autoloader.php');
    $feed = new SimplePie();
    $feed->set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/');
    ...
?>
```

Then when I upload it to the server, I get this shown:

```
set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/'); $feed->init(); $feed->handle_content_type(); print 'test'; ?>
```

I have a phpBB forum installed as well, it works like charm. So > works like ?> in my code. I have no more php on that page, and commenting out the line does not help at all. Also I tried to add echo and print, but it did not work. So the PHP Version 5.2.17 is running... I have no idea what the problem is and how to solve it... Help me, please.

P.S. I know this thing will fix it half the way:

```
<?php
    require_once('../autoloader.php');
    $feed = new SimplePie();

    $function = set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/');
    call_user_func(array($feed), $function);

    $function = init();
    call_user_func(array($feed), $function);

    $function = handle_content_type();
    call_user_func(array($feed), $function);
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like PHP is not running on the file at all, and the browser is interpreting `<?php blah >` as an unknown tag.

Comment: i am so dumb :P I have .html extension on the file. Thanks.